# How to edit data after public data on website Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I created report from Power BI Desktop and public report on website Power BI. But It has wrong data. Can I edit data on website Power BI.

Comment: It depends on the datasource used. You may be able to refresh the databaset, you may have to install Power BI Gateway to make this possible, or worst case you will have to re-publish your report with updated data.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do with your report in the editing view of the online service, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-interact-with-a-report-in-editing-view

However, **changing the underlying data** or even the datamodel **is not possible**. This can only be done in the desktop application.